# Web api aspnet Json formatter preformance test

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, protocol-buffers, jil

Up until now my team used the built in Json.Net Json formatter in web application. Now I want to test different formatters such as Jil or Protobuf to Serialize and Deserialize faster.

My question is How do I check Serialization/Deserialization preformance in a web api application?
I want to prove that other formatters are better and don't know how

Comment: Run them on your exact use cases, measure the time, CPU and RAM they take then make a decision. Or see if there are existing benchmarks online.

Comment: How do I measure those things while exexuting an http request?

Comment: There are plenty of performance monitoring tools out there. Visual Studio 2015 has a built in diagnostic tool, JetBrains builds one and there are others which you can find on Google. If you can't use any of those tools just add a timer to the controller actions and log the time it takes. Besides you don't need to log the entire HTTP request, just the serialization part.